# What will happen if I trim a honeylocust in the spring?

Tags: honey-locust, trimming

Every website advises that I trim a honeylocust in the fall after the leaves have fallen, or in the spring before the sap starts to rise.

However, my young honeylocust (established for 3 years, 15 feet tall?) has gotten very excited, and each branch grew about 3 feet (!) this spring, and several branches are now hanging over (basically blocking) our front walkway.

It seems unfriendly too our mailman to block the walkway to the door for six months, so I'm thinking of trimming several branches now, right at the end of spring.

What will happen if I do that? Any other advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are tough trees so the short answer is not much.  Where I live by June the major rush of new growth is over:  trees have leaved out and the spring rush is over.

Pruning done now will probably cause new growth at the site of the cuts which you would not get if you pruned in fall or winter.

Do what you need to do but try to limit  your pruning to smaller branches, say pencil thickness or less.  If you take off larger diameter branches you will get [water sprouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_sprout) and need to do more work to remove those.